# How to keep the order of the records added in a many2many field the way I wrote them?

Tags: odoo-15

I want to keep the order of the records in the many2many field, the way I added them using the write method, but Odoo use the alphanumerical order by default and overwrote the order I put them in. How can I keep it in the same order when I wrote them, is that possible ?
Here is the model code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api


class projet_richat(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    competence_ids = fields.Many2many('competence.competence',string='Compétences')
    consultants=fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string="Consultants")


    def search_comp(self):
        if len(self.competence_ids) != 0:
            consults=self.env['hr.employee'].sudo().search([])
            list=[]
            for cmp in self.competence_ids:
                print(cmp.competence)
                for cons in consults:
                    print(cons.name)
                    for c in cons.competences:
                        if c.competence.competence==cmp.competence:
                            list.append((cons.id,c.competence.competence,c.niveau))
            sorted_by_level = sorted(list, key=lambda tup: tup[2], reverse=True)
            print(sorted_by_level)
            for sorted_cons in sorted_by_level:
                self.write({'consultants': [[4, sorted_cons[0]]]})
```

and here is the view code:

```
    <odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="project_inherit_form">
            <field name="name">project.inherit.form</field>
            <field name="model">project.task</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>

            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="user_ids" position="before">

                    <field name="competence_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>


                </field>
                <field name="parent_id" position="after">


                    <field name="consultants">
                        <tree>

                            <field name="name"/>


                        </tree>
                    </field>

                </field>
                <button name="action_assign_to_me" position="after">
                    <button name="search_comp" string="Test" class="btn-primary"
                            type="object"
                    />
                </button>


            </field>


        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The many2many field will use the list view to show its content, the default order is defined by the [_order](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.BaseModel._order) attribute on the related model.
You can alter the default ordering by setting the [default_order](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/views.html#list) parameter on the `tree` tag

From the `List` view documentation:

> **default_order**
> overrides the ordering of the view, replacing the model’s order ([_order](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.BaseModel._order) model 
> attribute). The value is a comma-separated list of fields, postfixed by desc to 
> sort in reverse order:

```xml
<tree default_order="sequence,name desc">
```

To keep the order you want, you can add an integer field `sequence` and use it to order records (`_order='sequence'`) then in `search_comp` function set the sequence field value for each line